# SUPER CSV write bean to CSV

Tags: java, csv, javabeans, supercsv

Here is my class,

```
public class FreebasePeopleResults {

public String intendedSearch;
public String weight;
public Double heightMeters;
public Integer age;
public String type;
public String parents;
public String profession;
public String alias;
public String children;
public String siblings;
public String spouse;
public String degree;
public String institution;
public String wikipediaId;
public String guid;
public String id;
public String gender;
public String name;
public String ethnicity;
public String articleText;
public String dob;

public String getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
public void setWeight(String weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}
public Double getHeightMeters() {
    return heightMeters;
}
public void setHeightMeters(Double heightMeters) {
    this.heightMeters = heightMeters;
}
public String getParents() {
    return parents;
}
public void setParents(String parents) {
    this.parents = parents;
}
public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}       
public String getProfession() {
    return profession;
}
public void setProfession(String profession) {
    this.profession = profession;
}
public String getAlias() {
    return alias;
}
public void setAlias(String alias) {
    this.alias = alias;
}
public String getChildren() {
    return children;
}
public void setChildren(String children) {
    this.children = children;
}
public String getSpouse() {
    return spouse;
}
public void setSpouse(String spouse) {
    this.spouse = spouse;
}
public String getDegree() {
    return degree;
}
public void setDegree(String degree) {
    this.degree = degree;
}
public String getInstitution() {
    return institution;
}
public void setInstitution(String institution) {
    this.institution = institution;
}
public String getWikipediaId() {
    return wikipediaId;
}
public void setWikipediaId(String wikipediaId) {
    this.wikipediaId = wikipediaId;
}
public String getGuid() {
    return guid;
}
public void setGuid(String guid) {
    this.guid = guid;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}
public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEthnicity() {
    return ethnicity;
}
public void setEthnicity(String ethnicity) {
    this.ethnicity = ethnicity;
}
public String getArticleText() {
    return articleText;
}
public void setArticleText(String articleText) {
    this.articleText = articleText;
}
public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
public String getType() {
    return type;
}
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}
public String getSiblings() {
    return siblings;
}
public void setSiblings(String siblings) {
    this.siblings = siblings;
}
public String getIntendedSearch() {
    return intendedSearch;
}
public void setIntendedSearch(String intendedSearch) {
    this.intendedSearch = intendedSearch;
}
```

}

Here is my CSV writer method

```
 import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.supercsv.io.CsvBeanWriter;
import org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference;

public class CSVUtils {

    public static void writeCSVFromList(ArrayList<FreebasePeopleResults> people, boolean writeHeader) throws IOException{

        //String[] header = new String []{"title","acronym","globalId","interfaceId","developer","description","publisher","genre","subGenre","platform","esrb","reviewScore","releaseDate","price","cheatArticleId"};
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("/brian/brian/Documents/people-freebase.csv", true);

        // write the partial data
        CsvBeanWriter writer = new CsvBeanWriter(file, CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE);

        for(FreebasePeopleResults person:people){
            writer.write(person);
        }
        writer.close();
        // show output
    }           
}
```

I keep getting output errors. Here is the error: 
There is no content to write for line 2 context: Line: 2 Column: 0 Raw line:
null

Now, I know it is now totally null, so I am confused.

Comment: SuperCSV. You can find it here. I am new to java, and I am a little confused at why this error is occurring. 
http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it's been a while, and you've probably moved on from this, but...

The issue was actually that you weren't supplying the header to the `write()` method, i.e. it should be

```
writer.write(person, header);
```

Unfortunately the API is a little misleading in it's use of the var-args notation in the signature of the `write()` method, as it allows `null` to be passed in. The javadoc clearly states that you shouldn't do this, but there was no null-check in the implementation: hence the exception you were getting.

```
/**
 * Write an object
 * 
 * @param source
 *            at object (bean instance) whose values to extract
 * @param nameMapping
 *            defines the fields of the class that must be written. 
 *            null values are not allowed
 * @since 1.0
 */
public void write(Object source, String... nameMapping) throws IOException,
    SuperCSVReflectionException;
```

[Super CSV 2.0.0-beta-1](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/release_notes.html) is out now. It retains the var-args in the `write()` method, but fails fast if you provide a null, so you know exactly what's wrong when you get a NullPointerException with the following:

> the nameMapping array can't be null as it's used to map from fields to
>   columns

It also includes many bug fixes and new features (including Maven support and a new Dozer extension for mapping nested properties and arrays/Collections).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see where you create `ArrayList<FreebasePeopleResults> people`, but you might verify that it has more than one element. As an example of [coding to the interface](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1999/jw-08-interfaces.html), consider using `List<FreebasePeopleResults> people` as the formal parameter.

Addendum: Have you been able to make this [*Code example: Write a file with a header*](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/codeExamples_general.html) work?

Example: Here's a simplified example. I think you just need to specify the `nameMapping` when you invoke `write()`. Those names determine what get methods to call via introspection.

Console output:

```
name,age
Alpha,1
Beta,2
Gamma,3
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.supercsv.io.CsvBeanWriter;
import org.supercsv.io.ICsvBeanWriter;
import org.supercsv.prefs.CsvPreference;

public class Main {

    private static final List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        people.add(new Person("Alpha", 1));
        people.add(new Person("Beta", 2));
        people.add(new Person("Gamma", 3));
        ICsvBeanWriter writer = new CsvBeanWriter(
            new PrintWriter(System.out), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
        try {
            final String[] nameMapping = new String[]{"name", "age"};
            writer.writeHeader(nameMapping);
            for (Person p : people) {
                writer.write(p, nameMapping);
            }
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}

public class Person {

    String name;
    Integer age;

    public Person(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are saying use List type instead of ArrayList?

Comment: And I create ArrayList<FreebasePeopleResults> people in another method and pass it in.
I know that it has data because if i do a sysout (person.name) I will see it in my console.

Comment: @Butters: Yes, `List<type>`, but that's tangential to your problem. What field should be in column 0?

Comment: I must be incorrectly implementing this method because I thought it was going to pull the first field in the class and write it, and move along.

Answer (score 2):

```
CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] { new Optional(), new NotNull(),
                new Optional(), new Optional(), new NotNull(), new Optional()};

CsvBeanWriter writer = new CsvBeanWriter(file, CsvPreference.EXCEL_PREFERENCE)

writer.write(data,properties,processors);
```